# Word for "little insect"

Tags: single-word-requests, entomology

What's the best word for small kind animals such as earthworms, butterflies and caterpillars but not the bad bugs like flies, mosquitoes and cockroaches?

The word may refer to the bad bugs, but it should sound sweet and kindly, and girls may use it as a nickname.

Comment: I think whatever nickname you come up with could be used by girls or boys; seems like an unnecessary distinction to me.

Comment: Butterfiles are alright but (at least in American culture) earthworms are traditionally seen as associated with mud and dirt and therefore "gross" to little girls and "cool" to little boys. Caterpillers as well, though less so. Bugs in general are seen as a "boy" thing unless they're exceedingly pretty like butterflies are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In English these are all simply *bugs*. There is no cultural notion of good vs. bad, but there are a few expressions like *snug as a bug* that imply this.

I think *bug* is about as close as you can get, something like *little bug* works fine as a cute nickname. Otherwise there are only negative forms for insects, such as *pests* or *vermin*.

Instead of trying to fit one word for a class of "cute insects", you could choose a particular kind. This also makes it more personal and endearing. Consider:

- Honeybee
- Pillbug
- Ladybug (ladybird)
- Butterfly
- Cricket

I can add that Czech also has the same idea of "cute bug" ("brouček") as a diminutive nickname, so I understand your question. There's no real equivalent in English.

Comment: I think *bug* is sometimes used as a "nickname". I have the feeling American parents [did?] use it for their kid sometimes, along the lines of *slugger*, or *sport*. But I'm not American; maybe I've just seen too many Disney movies where they make this kind of thing up.

Comment: @FumbleFingers my daughter was often "Bellebug", a play on her name.

Answer (score 1):

In informal contexts, you could try *beastie* (Scottish?), *creepy-crawly* or, in South Africa apparently, *gogga*.

Answer (score 1):

What about [creepy-crawlies](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/creepy-crawly).

That tends to be used when portraying insects more positively.

Comment: Yes, it is positive. But they seem like have hard joints, maybe more suitable for boys?

Comment: Are you suggesting that this would be a good nickname for a girl? (which is the OPs intent).

Answer (score 1):

In the US, *grasshopper* is used as a sobriquet, and (less frequently) *katydid* and *honeybee* too.   If you want other insect names or tags to try out as nicknames, consider *bumblebee*, *worker bee*, *maybug* or *mayfly*, *damselfly*, *dragonfly*, and *leafhopper*.

I don't know of a small-insects class-name with positive connotations (*i.e.* regard *creepy-crawly* as negative, and believe *[beastie](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beastie)* denotes animals rather than insects), and don't know of any nicknames based on such a class-name.

Answer (score 0):

Diminutives always make things sound cuter, so how about 'buggy'.

Comment: Well.. buggy make me think of a piece of program error-prone.. The problem is, the word bug- sounds a little rude, would girls like it? (In Chinese, `虫子 chóng zi` sounds more gentle, or `むし mushi` in Japanese, though..)

Comment: It makes me think of the vehicle you drive around a golf course.

Comment: You could make it "cuter" by going with something like *buggy-bug*